# Gauss Markov Process

Tags: random, signal-processing

I am trying to model a 1st order Gauss Markov Process (gyroscope drift). I know the  Allan Variance characteristics of the process (bias instability, random walk characteristics).

I know the model should look like:

```
RandomFunction[SomeProcess[some_process_args], {some_time_characteristics}]
```

but not quite sure where to start. I looked up `ARProcess` but it only seems to work with a unit time increment

Comment: Cross posted it on dap.stackexchange….

Comment: This question is too vague to meaningful to anybody other than an expert in Gauss Markov processes. You may get lucky and find one here, but otherwise you are going need to supply much more information in the form of _Mathematica_ examples to elicit and answer.

Comment: Please do not cross-post to multiple sites. This is on-topic for [dsp.se], and your issue seems more fundamental than a specific _Mathematica_ problem. I suggest deleting this and focusing on the DSP question. If you get a reply there and you have a specific model that you need help implementing in _Mathematica_, then post a question with all the relevant details and document your efforts.

Comment: Sorry for the cross post…. 

I figured out a way to do this… in case anyone is in future…

    rate  =  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, stdevARW], time*f] + RandomFunction[WienerProcess[drift, volatility], {1/f, time, 1/f}]["Path"][[All, 2]];

Comment: Answer your own question it's ok!

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question

I figured out a way to do this… in case anyone is interested…

```
rate  =  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, stdevARW], time] + RandomFunction[WienerProcess[drift, volatility], {1/f, time, 1/f}]["Path"][[All, 2]];
```